# Short story about a drug addict in a prison in Mexico

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I remember reading a short story on the internet a decade or so ago. It was told in first person, from the perspective of a middle class (male?) in the USA, who had some kind of medical problem that was treated with legal opiate patches. One day he finds that he can get a much better effect if he consumes a patch in a shorter timeframe, but this results in him running out of patches before his next dose could be legally obtained. Thus he turns to illegal ways, which lead to him traveling to Mexico in his car to buy more for less money.

On the way back he is caught by the border agents of Mexico and detained in prison under horribly inhumane circumstances, like the only source of "drinkable" water being the bucket used to mop the floor. His suffering is quite detailed as he goes through the "cold turkey" withdrawal process after years of addiction to a hard drug.

After a while he is told that his withdrawal symptoms have confirmed that he is addicted to the stuff himself and not a dealer, so he is let go now that he is clean. But he finds that the guards have maxed out his credit cards, only leaving him a small amount (50$?) of cash. He buys a lot of soda for 4$ to cure his dehydration and heads back towards the border with total clarity and a renewed sense of purpose.

> Then on the way back to the border he encounters a dealer selling the same kind of patches, on which he spends his remaining 46$. AFAIK the story ends with these exact words: "How many for 46$?"

I have tried searching with Google for the main keywords, like "mexico", "prison" and "drugs", resulting only in lots of unrelated hits (and probably landing me on some kind of government agency watchlist...)